# How to choose an epoxy?

Tags: epoxy

The question is spurned by the fact that I've got a good deal of olive-wood scrap from creating utensils. I'd like to epoxy it all together and then turn a bowl out of them. In looking at epoxy, there are a lot of options along a fairly wide distribution of price points.

**So, what should one look for in an epoxy for this use?** Does anything change if looking to add color/dye to the epoxy? Are any epoxies considered food safe at the end of the day?

Edit to add: The scrap size is mostly 1.5"x.75"x.5" (about a handful) and some larger pieces going up to 3"x2"x.75". It is my plan to stack all of the pieces into a Tupperware container, layer in the epoxy, then turn the bowl. In the end, the bowl may be about 60-75% wood, 25-40% epoxy.

Thanks!

Comment: How much gap filling do you need to glue the majority of the scraps together? If you just need epoxy for filling some gaps then it's arguably it's better to glue the bulk of the item together with something else, reserving the epoxy for voids only. As for the colouring, from what I've read and observed firsthand the cost of the epoxy makes zero difference to success.

Comment: Epoxy is generally food safe when cured, though most (all?) of them contain BPA.  (Of course, so do most metal cans and many beverage containers.)

Comment: @Graphus see edits. Mostly pretty small pieces, but it may be more than a fill-gap amount.

Comment: I think your best bet here is just to use one of the epoxies that other turners use for similar purposes. I'm fairly sure there's at least two YouTubers who do this kind of work, and probably numerous others! I'll bet right now that many of them will use a West Systems epoxy, some Smooth-On and a few Devcon, not that your choice is limited to only these three by any means. On the food safety thing, do a quick search here and you'll see it's basically a non-issue once finish/glue/resins are cured.